# jquery append function converting < > to entity name

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, imagemap

I am using getJSON to get a JSON file and then build the image map hotspots based on the data retrieved.
This is being used in a seating chart application where the station numbers stay the same, but the name of the individuals always change.

After I get the data I loop trough it and create the image hotspots like this (I am using # as a place holder for the href for now).

```
 $('#maphall').append('< area class="'+ val.class +
 '" shape="'+val.shape+'" href="'+val.href+'" id = "'+
 val.id+'" coords='+val.coords+' />');
```

When I look at the generated code in FireFox I see:

```
&lt; area class="room" shape="rect" href="#" id = "2B" coords="160,56,279,109" /&gt;
```

How do I get the < and > to appear instead of `&lt;` and `&gt;` ?

Comment: why do you have a space between `<` and `area` ?

Comment: Removing the space fixed the problem. Please put that as an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML parsers will treat a `<` followed by a space as a less than sign and not the start of a tag.

Serialising the DOM back to HTML will show it as an entity.

Write valid HTML. Remove the space.